# Why can't I use 32-bit ints array in ASM.js?

Tags: javascript, firefox, emscripten, arraybuffer, asm.js

This code works in Firefox nicely - though for some reason, changing the Uint8Array into Uint32array, breaks. Do I need to coerce numbers differently in that case?

```
 function Module(stdlib, foreign, heap) {
      "use asm";

      // Variable Declarations
      var els = new stdlib.Uint8Array(heap);

      // Function Declarations
      function firstn(x) {
          x = x|0 //32-bit (int)
          var i=0;
          for (; (i|0) < (x|0); i = (i+1)|0) {
              els[i] = i;
          }
      }

      return { firstn: firstn };
  }

  buf = ArrayBuffer(1024*8)

  f = Module(window,{},buf).firstn;
  f(5)
  console.log(new Uint8Array(buf));
```

And one more thing - is it possible to send an arraybuffer, and have a reference to the final array it produces, with C++ emscriptem-compiled asm.js too?

Comment: What is breaking, exactly?  And which of the two Uint8Array callsites are you changing to Uint32Array?  Or are you changing both of them?

Comment: When I change the Uint8Arrays to Uint32Arrays, it doesn't compile - probably due to needing to use different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like asm.js only allows indexing into an Int32Array or Uint32Array using an expression of the form (foo >> 2), though I can't find any reference to this in the spec.  That is, it assumes that what you have is an address and are trying to look up the integer at that address.  I guess that makes sense, kinda since C code like this:

```
int32_t arr[5];
arr[i];
```

would get compiled down to machine code that does the equivalent of `*((char*)arr + 4*i)`...  Anyway, replacing `els[i] = i` in your code with:

```
  els[(i<<2)>>2] = i;
```

seems to make things work with a Uint32Array.

Comment: Thanks! That's great, how did you find that? I don't see how doubling and halving it fixes that - and oddly enough, it doesn't work when I use the Fibonacci calculation like so: `els[(i<<2)>>2] = (els[((i-1)<<2)>>2] + els[((i-2)<<2)>>2])|0`

Comment: I found it by looking for the validation error message involved in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jit/AsmJS.cpp and then reading the surrounding code.  Not exactly a user-friendly process, I know.  As for Fibonacci, it looks like you need to explicitly cast the results of the array reads to int, like so: `els[(i<<2)>>2] = (els[((i-1) << 2) >> 2]|0) + (els[((i-2) << 2) >> 2]|0);`.  I'm not sure why it can't just assume a Uint32Array read is typed "unsigned"; it thinks the type is "intish".